# 64 to 16 bit hash key

Tags: c, hash

What is the most efficient way of hashing 64 bit values to 16 bit values, something like the following function.

```
int16 hashfunction( int64 );
```

With least probability of collision.

Comment: Are the values to be hashed known in advance?

Comment: What's the distribution of your input values?

Comment: To estimate the probability of collision something about the data needs to be known. Otherwise, for random 64 bit quantities simply taking the low-order 16 bits is as efficient and collision free as any other hash function.

Comment: OK, since you've started accepting some answers... as a naive idea, just to illustrate why you should think a bit more about the nature of your data, if you knew that all your input would be < 10000, you could just truncate to 16bit and have a perfect hash. If your input is uniformly distributed, then the truncation to any number of bits would again be uniform. So it's really a question of what you want. If you want lots of decorrelation (nearby numbers give arbitrarily distant hashes), you should look at some other (cryptographic?) hash algorithms, maybe the proposed CRC16.

Comment: Don't try to do such things with signed quantities. When you do hashing most probably you just want to see the values as bit pattern, so use `uint64_t` and `uint16_t` then.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt thanks, but I think it works well as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple one could look like this:

```
int16 hashfunction( int64 i )
{
    int16 hash = (int16)(i & 0xFFFF);
    hash ^= (int16)((i >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
    hash ^= (int16)((i >> 32) & 0xFFFF);
    hash ^= (int16)((i >> 48) & 0xFFFF);

    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Donald Knuth would probably downvote it.  See http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx

Comment: Donald Knuth was after a perfect hash. I don't claim this is perfect. In fact this is pretty naive and textbook. But it does what the OP wants with minimal effort. There are other answers, maybe someone should propose a better one.

Comment: @Chris: "perfect hash" is a technical term, you might want to say "ideal" or "optimal" instead.

Comment: @Dietrich: perfect, ideal, optimal -- they all mean a hash space with no collisions for the input domain. This is not that.

Comment: @Chris: "Perfect hash" means no collisions.  Where have you seen "ideal" or "optimal" used that way?  I have seen references to "ideal perfect hashes" which are injective and surjective, for example... but in these writings it is always clear that "perfect hash" is the term for "injective hash function".

Comment: Thanks hans. The link you provided was very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

I guess a CRC16 would be the best option?

Update: Directly from the Linux Kernel source! CRC16 for you.

```
/*
 *      crc16.c
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the GNU General Public License,
 * Version 2. See the file COPYING for more details.
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2005 Ben Gardner <bgardner@wabtec.com>
 */

#include <linux/types.h>

/** CRC table for the CRC-16. The poly is 0x8005 (x^16 + x^15 + x^2 + 1) */
u16 const crc16_table[256] = {
        0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
        0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
        0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
        0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
        0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
        0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
        0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
        0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
        0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
        0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
        0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
        0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
        0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
        0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
        0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
        0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,
        0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
        0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
        0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
        0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
        0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
        0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
        0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
        0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,
        0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
        0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
        0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
        0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
        0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
        0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
        0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
        0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040
};

static inline u16 crc16_byte(u16 crc, const u8 data)
{
    return (crc >> 8) ^ crc16_table[(crc ^ data) & 0xff];
}

/**
 * crc16 - compute the CRC-16 for the data buffer
 * @crc:        previous CRC value
 * @buffer:     data pointer
 * @len:        number of bytes in the buffer
 *
 * Returns the updated CRC value.
 */
u16 crc16(u16 crc, u8 const *buffer, size_t len)
{
        while (len--)
                crc = crc16_byte(crc, *buffer++);
        return crc;
}
```

Comment: Wow, you even kept the ugly indentation style of Linus.